# Doing a select on three tables merging into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I need to do a select on three tables, then in the resulting view have the fields from each select.  The three tables are :

```
 Accounts Payable, Accounts Receivable, General Ledger
```

The fields I want are :

```
 ID, Paid, PaidDate, source, or some variation from each table.
```

The resulting view would be something like:

```
T1F1, T1F2, T1F3, T1F4, T2F1, T2F2, T2F3, T2F4, T3F1, T3F2, T3F3, T3F4
```

There T is the table, and F is the selected field.

Is there a way to do with against Postgresql?  I looked at JOIN, but there are no links between the three tables.  Each table has a some of the transaction against a GL account.  What I need is a printout that contains the transactions from all three tables in date order.  The actual problem is one table is deposits to the bank, one is cheques written, the other is service fees etc.  That I need to print out is sort of a bank statement in date order including deposits, withdraws and misc.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp read up on Joins

Answer (score 0):

You can use join  (inner if the key between the tables eber match , left if not)

```
 select T1F1, T1F2, T1F3, T1F4, T2F1, T2F2, T2F3, T2F4, T3F1, T3F2, T3F3, T3F4
 from TF1 
 INNER JOIN T2 ON (T1.Key = T2.Key)
 INNER JOIN T3 ON (T1.key = T3.Key)
```

You should look at your table schema for getb the proper key

this is a tutorial https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at doing an outer join if your GL table doesn't necessarily have entries in the other two tables.  T1 here would be your GL table.

```
select T1F1, T1F2, T1F3, T1F4, T2F1, T2F2, T2F3, T2F4, T3F1, T3F2, T3F3, T3F4
 from TF1 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON (T1.Key = T2.Key)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 ON (T1.key = T3.Key)
```